# Should I edit "MY" accepted answer to show that it will be further edited?

Tags: discussion

Research into an "accepted" answer I've given compels me to edit the answer to better address the scope of the question and provide a more accurate answer. Even more so, now that it's been accepted and will be the first reference everyone sees.

I'd like some outside opinions of what some of you would opt to do in this case.

To forewarn viewers: Should I edit the answer to say "This answer will be edited upon further research"? Should I finish researching it and then supply a better answer?

Or should I edit (update) it to include a few references I've found, so people can research it themselves, as I try to provide a more refined answer?

Comment: You can leave a comment on your answer too, and then delete it after the edits.

Comment: That's a great idea and is exactly what I will do thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Samuel Liew [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400347/should-i-edit-my-accepted-answer-to-show-that-it-will-be-further-edited#comment789887_400347) in the comments:

> You can leave a comment on your answer too, and then delete it after the edits.

This is a good strategy because edits to a question or any of its answers will bump that question to the front page of stackoverflow.com.  Posting comments (or removing them) doesn't bump the question.

In this situation, you probably don't want people to take a second look at your answer until you're finished your additional research and edits, so you wouldn't want to bump it until you're done improving it.  Posting the comment will provide the information to anyone viewing the answer without bumping it, and your edit will push it to the front page for people to see once your improvements are done.